# How to make dynamic data in Javascript from Django views

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have js like this, I want make that data is dynamic from database. I want to pass that value from views. How to do that?

```
data: [          
                {
                value: 335,
                name: 'Coding'
                }, {
                value: 310,
                name: 'Database'
                }, {
                value: 234,
                name: 'UIX'
                }, {
                value: 135,
                name: 'Manajemen'
                },]
```

I try this code :

```
cursor.execute('SELECT k.nama_ktg as name, COUNT(m.nim) as value FROM mahasiswa_mhs_si m, mata_kuliah_kategori_utama u, mata_kuliah_kategori k WHERE k.kode_ktgu_id = u.id AND m.kode_ktg_id = k.id  GROUP BY k.id')
    ktg_mhs = cursor.fetchall()

    #JSON CHART
    result = []
           
    chart_ktg =[
    {
        'value' : ktg_mhsi[1],
        'name' : ktg_mhsi[0]
    }
        for ktg_mhsi in ktg_mhs
    ]
    data = json.dumps(chart_ktg)
```

And the result is this :

```
[{"value": 51, "name": "Coding"}, {"value": 27, "name": "Database"}, {"value": 223, "name": "UI/UX"}, {"value": 34, "name": "Manajemen"}, {"value": 7, "name": "Dasar Sistem Informasi"}, {"value": 64, "name": "Bisnis"}, {"value": 18, "name": "Kesehatan"}, {"value": 235, "name": "Lain-lain"}]
```